# Show certain slides only on specific urls on views slideshow

Tags: 7, views

Using views slideshow I want to be able to control what nodes of content type "slides" show depending on what URL, any ideas?  for example on page-front I would like to show slide1 and slide2, on node/43 I would like to show slide3 and slide4.

Having separate views is not an option because this is a slider that is on hundreds of pages and different content types.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be better off having two separate views for the two URLs? If you do need this done in a single view, you will need to write custom module that adds filters to the view. Try using contrib module called [views_arg_context](https://drupal.org/project/views_arg_context)

Comment: we want to do this for every url of the site that has this view, it is on multiple content types and hundreds of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Normally answer is Contextual Filters; but i am not sure that i understood your problem definately. What is your criterion (nid, content type, date, taxonomy etc.) to relate node/43 and slides 3-4? If there is a relation between node/43 and slides 3-4, then you can filter them using Contextual Filters (Or, if possible, you could need to create a Relationship first.). If there is no relation/criterion, you could add an additional field to relevant content type(s) and fill it manually or automatically, then filter by its value.